# What does the expression "< /dev/null some_command" do?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, io-redirection

I am somewhat familiar with redirecting and know that /dev/null can be used for hiding output, for example with

```
some_command > /dev/null
```

but I encountered the usage

```
< /dev/null some_command
```

in [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Convert_FLAC_to_MP3#With_FFmpeg) ArchWiki article and would like to understand what it does.

My first guess is that it is equivalent to

```
some_command < /dev/null
```

but if this guess is correct, what is the benefit of redirecting `/dev/null` to a command?

Comment: /dev/null is equivalent to an empty file, if used as input. You could also create an empty file and use that as the input. But /dev/null is handy because it is there (for that reason)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they're equivalent. I/O redirection can be put anywhere on the command line.

When reading, `/dev/null` returns EOF immediately. Redirecting input from `/dev/null` is useful if you want to prevent the application from trying to read from whatever its initial standard input is, e.g. the terminal.

A common use of this is when running a program in the background via SSH and you want the SSH connection to close immediately. The connection won't close until all the file descriptors referring to it are closed, so you redirect all the standard descriptors:

```
ssh servername 'somecommand </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &'
```